# Google php sdk invalid authentication credentials

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to upload a video with the [php google sdk](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client). I already obtained successfully a bearer token, it looks like this (modified the access token):

```
array:5 [▼ 
  "access_token" => "ya29.a0AWY7Cklr25-2pFLjBo2jyXbNVPWnSR8wGwLpupH-rNchLnHYTd-s4xAE7_hJxkSO1XEp_yleWyYIFdePcFLxlGjbXfDizYxSBRJByPpF-syjv6DHB1pgY42mKfqZQG1tDrpeI1Qdh8nsQXHJ2z9PozvQA015 ◀"
  "expires_in" => 3599
  "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
  "token_type" => "Bearer"
  "created" => 16841898
]
```

I keep receiving back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

When I try to use the php sdk client like this, and then make calls with this client:

```
$client = new \Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('google_client_secrets.json'));
$client->setAccessToken(
    'ya29.a0AWY7Cklr25-2pFLjBo2jyXbNVPWnSR8wGwLpupH-rNchLnHYTd-s4xAE7_hJxkSO1XEp_yleWyYIFdePcFLxlGjbXfDizYxSBRJByPpF-syjv6DHB1pgY42mKfqZQG1tDrpeI1Qdh8nsQXHJ2z9PozvQA015'
);

$youtubeService = new \Google_Service_YouTube($client);
```

Why is this the case? It looks like the token is valid.

Comment: Please replicate your request on [playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). The Youtube API is enabled at GCP I suppose.